# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, javafx, error-handling

I'm in the process of developing a simple matching card game which javacs perfectly fine, but whenever you click on a card it gives me this error. Once you click the card its suppose to add to the counter, if the counter = 1 its suppose to store the card so it can be compared once the counter = 2. I'm fairly new to java so I don't know how to solve this, any help would be appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
    at FinalProjectTest$1.handle(FinalProjectTest.java:120)
    at FinalProjectTest$1.handle(FinalProjectTest.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3760)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3488)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1765)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2497)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:411)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:941)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)**
```

My code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class FinalProjectTest extends Application
{
    private Button button = new Button();
    private Button button1 = new Button();
    private Button button2 = new Button();
    private Button button3 = new Button();
    private Button button4 = new Button();
    private List<Card> cards; //Recommend using the more general List interface
    private Card firstCard;
    private Image backCard;
    private ImageView backCardIView;
    private ImageView backCardIView1;
    private ImageView backCardIView2;
    private ImageView backCardIView3;
    private ImageView backCardIView4;
    private ImageView backCardIView5;
    private int counter = 0;
    private int counter1 = 0;
    private Label label;
 
enum Card {
    CLUBS_2("file:2_Clubs.jpg", 2), DIAMONDS_2("file:2_Diamonds.jpg", 2),
    CLUBS3("file:3_Clubs.jpg", 3), DIAMONDS3("file:3_Diamonds.jpg", 3);
 
    private final String filename;
    private final int value;
    Card(String filename, int value) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.value = value;
    }
}  
 
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
 
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)
{
    //startButton = new Button("Play!");
    
    label = new Label("YOU WIN!");
    label.setVisible(false);
     
    GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
    gridpane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
     
    gridpane.add(button, 0, 0);
    gridpane.add(button1, 2, 0);
    gridpane.add(button2, 0, 1);
    gridpane.add(button3, 2, 1);
    gridpane.add(label, 1, 2);
     
    backCard = new Image("file:backCard.jpg");
     
    backCardIView = new ImageView(backCard);
    backCardIView1 = new ImageView(backCard);
    backCardIView2 = new ImageView(backCard);
    backCardIView3 = new ImageView(backCard);
    backCardIView4 = new ImageView(backCard);
    backCardIView5 = new ImageView(backCard);
     
    backCardIView.setFitWidth(100);
    backCardIView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    backCardIView1.setFitWidth(100);
    backCardIView1.setPreserveRatio(true);
    backCardIView2.setFitWidth(100);
    backCardIView2.setPreserveRatio(true);
    backCardIView3.setFitWidth(100);
    backCardIView3.setPreserveRatio(true);
    backCardIView4.setFitWidth(100);
    backCardIView4.setPreserveRatio(true);
    backCardIView5.setFitWidth(100);
    backCardIView5.setPreserveRatio(true);
     
    button.setGraphic(backCardIView);
    button1.setGraphic(backCardIView1);
    button2.setGraphic(backCardIView2);
    button3.setGraphic(backCardIView3);
     
    //Convert the Card enumeration to a List (under the hood it's still an ArrayList in this case)
    cards = Arrays.asList(Card.values());
    java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);
     
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event)
        {    
            Card card = cards.remove(0);
             
            counter++;
            if (counter == 1) {
                firstCard = card;
                 
                //You could also use button.getGraphic(graphic); here, but the method below would let
                //you avoid repeating these EventHandlers and use a single EventHandler.
                //The event's source is.. the source of the event, which is the button in this case.
                Button buttonClicked = ((Button)event.getSource());
                buttonClicked.setGraphic(new ImageView(card.filename));
            } else {
                compareCards(card);
                counter = 0;//You'll need to reset the counter once you hit 2
            }
        }
    });
     
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(gridpane);
     
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Matching");
    primaryStage.show();
}

    private void compareCards(Card secondCard) {
    //Compare firstCard which was already set with secondCard passed in here
    
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__!

Comment: ahh ..  please read the java doc of Arrays.asList to understand what's wrong :)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Baeldung has a great explanation: [Arrays.asList vs new ArrayList(Arrays.asList())](https://www.baeldung.com/java-arrays-aslist-vs-new-arraylist)

Comment: In recent version Java versions, the javadoc for the asList function has been improved, [java 17 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) mentions that arrays returned by the operation can return an `UnsupportedOperationException` for add and remove calls, but older [java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) does not.

Comment: @jewelsea certainly improved by spelling out the error but .. _fixed-size_ it was always, and a good enough hint, IMO :)